# List index out of range with three for loops (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out all the dates between the 1st of January 1900 to the 31st of December 2099. I know that this can probably be done with an easier pre-made method, but I need to do it manually. Here is my code:

```
empty = []
years = [x for x in range(1900, 2100)]

months = {1:31, 2: 28, 3:31, 3:30, 5:31, 6:30,7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}

def calculate_my_age ():
    for i in years:
        for k in months:
            for x in range(1, months[k]):
                empty.append(x, k,years[i])
    return empty
print calculate_my_age()
```

When I run it in the terminal, it gives me an error on line 12, saying there's a list index out of range. I'm very new to this kind of stuff, so I probably wrote some nonsense! can you point out what the mistake is?

Comment: Why `years = [x for x in range(1900, 2100)]`? `years = range(1900, 2100)` does the same with less overhead.

Comment: oh, I didn't know I could do it that way. I have only just started learning, so I know very little python at this stage. thank you for this!

Comment: which is line 12 in your code?

Comment: @user3774945: In Python 2 `range` creates a list. If you switch to Python 3 you have to use `years = list(range(1900, 2100))`.

Comment: msturdy line 12 was the empty.append one...Thank you Matthias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
for i in years:
```

sets `i` in turn to the *contents* of the `years` list (e.g. `1900`), **not** the *indices* (e.g. `0`). Also, you can only `append` one thing at a time. Therefore your line 12 should be:

```
empty.append((x, k, i))
```

This gives e.g.:

```
>>> empty[:5]
[(1, 1, 1900), (2, 1, 1900), (3, 1, 1900), (4, 1, 1900), (5, 1, 1900)]
```

Note that you don't deal with leap years. Also, it would be better to pass `months` and `years` as *arguments* to `calculate_my_age`, define the empty list inside the function and `return` it at the end.

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe. Yes, I didn't deal with leap years. and Yes I am going to do that now as well as the other things you said. this one I posted was a "work-in-progress" version of my function :) thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `years[i]`:

```
def calculate_my_age ():
    for i in years:
        for k in months:
            for x in range(1, months[k]):
                empty.append(x, k, years[i]) # <------
    return empty
```

You just need `i` there as `i` is a year coming from years list, instead of `years[i]`.

```
def calculate_my_age ():
    for i in years:
        for k in months:
            for x in range(1, months[k]):
                empty.append((x, k, i))
    return empty
```

Also append takes only one argument you can not do `empty.append(x, k, i)` so I have used a tupple `empty.append((x, k, i))`.

Comment: Oh I see! thank you very much! I honestly don't know how i did't think about that!